# gccgo does not know -fgo-relative-import-path

Tags: compiler-errors, go, gccgo

I tried to compile some code with gccgo on my machine:

```
$ export LANG=C
$ go get -d github.com/fuzxxl/ppm
$ cd $GOPATH/src /github.com/fuzxxl/ppm
$ go build -compiler gcc
gccgo: error: unrecognized command line option '-fgo-relative-import-path=_/home/fuz/src/go/src/github.com/fuzxxl/ppm'
```

These are the tools on my machine:

```
$ go version
go version devel +dda87c8bcba1 Wed Apr 17 13:25:28 2013 -0700 linux/amd64
$ gccgo --version
gccgo (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Why do I get the error shown above? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-fgo-relative-import-path` option was [committed on 2012-10-30](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-10/msg02841.html%5d), whereas GCC 4.7.2 (including gccgo) was already [released on 2012-09-20](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/). So gccgo 4.7.2 simply does not yet contain support for this option.

Upgrading gccgo to 4.7.3 (or 4.8.0) should fix this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if there is any PPA that contains the newest gccgo version for Ubuntu?

Comment: The (as of today) upcoming Ubuntu 13.04 release will contain gccgo 4.7.3. I don't know of any PPA containing newer pre-built packages for the (as of today) current Ubuntu 12.10.